# In this function is defective since dereferencing null is not valid so i want to change code

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference, null-pointer

```
long cread(long *xp) {
  return (xp? *xp : 0);
}
```

It is invalid since it could attempt to read from a null address

So the solution suggested this code

```
long cread_alt(long *xp){
  long tem = 0;
  if(*xp > 0){
   tem = *xp;
  }
  return tem;
```

But I think it is also not valid since `if(*xp > 0)` is still defective when the `xp` is pointing a null address.

So I thought this code

```
 long cread_alt2(long *xp){
     long tem = 0;
     if(xp != NULL){
        tem = *xp;
     }
     return tem;
 }
```

Do I have this correct?

Comment: Your first snipped is perfectly valid. The 2nd one has undefined behaviour when `xp == nullptr`. The 3rd truncates a `long` to `int` on return.

Comment: The original function is perfectly fine. The second one is broken. The third is OK.

Comment: `return (xp? *xp : 0);` is equivalent to `if (xp != nullptr) {return *xp;}else{return 0;}`

Comment: Did you mean to make the return type of `cread_alt` and `cread_alt2` an `int`?

Answer (score 6):

```
long cread(long *xp) {
  return (xp? *xp : 0);
}
```

**is** valid and this is a very common technique.  The expression `pointer_name` can be converted to a `bool` and will be `false` if `pointer_name == nullptr` and `true` if `pointer_name != nullptr`.  That means for the above code that `*xp` only occurs when you do not have a null pointer.

```
int cread_alt2(long *xp){
    long tem = 0;
    if(xp != NULL){
        tem = *xp;
    }
    return tem;
}
```

Does the same thing, it is just much more verbose about it.  So, the only code that is actually invalid is `cread_alt`, which does dereference `xp` without first checking if it is null or not.

Comment: `cread_alt2()` also converts a `long` to an `int` on `return`.  It only does the same thing as `cread()` if `int` supports at least the range of values that `long` does, which is not required by the standard.

Comment: @Peter It was probably a typo from the OP.  I'll ask and if it is I'll update the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use of

```
if(xp != NULL){
  tem = *xp;
}
```

is valid. However, in your second snippet, you have

```
if(*xp > 0){
  tem = *xp;
}
```

Perhaps you want to use both.

```
if ( xp != NULL && *xp > 0 )
{
   tem = *xp;
}
```

If you are able to use C++11 or later, it is better coding practice to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

```
if ( xp != nullptr && *xp > 0 )
{
   tem = *xp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The original function is 100% valid code and it never dereferences the NULL pointer.

I think you should read the chapter about the ternary operators from your favourite C book

Comment: I write about the original code not about the alternatives